# Figuring out what this regex string replace does

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

With this code...

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/this/example/:id?q=help';
url = url.replace(/\\:/g, ':').replace(/\/?#$/, '').replace(/\/*$/, '');
```

What is each replace supposed to do?

I realize that it may not have any effect on the given string but theoretically, what is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the chain:

1. Replace all occurrences of `\:` by `:`.
2. Remove trailing fragment hash, including an optional slash that precedes it.
3. Remove any trailing slashes.

Comment: For 2... are you saying remove the exact occurrence of `/?#` or just any occurrence of those characters?

Comment: 2 strips either `/#` or `#` at the end of the string, not `/?#`. [? - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark)

Comment: @bflemi3 Sorry, I wasn't accurate enough; it removes a trailing hash which may be preceded by a slash.